# Android Fragment store ghost background Image

Tags: android, coverflow

I have one fragment with a lot of buttons and one fragment with coverflow gallery.
When I change from galery to coverflow and repeat the process and return to coverflow I can see some images at the background here how I create the fragment :

```
 FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();



     if(view == findViewById(R.id.button2)) {
         fr = new FragmentTwo();

     }else {
         fr = new FragmentOne();
     }       
     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
     fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);       
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to not show any animations etc from the fragment that is leaving, then simply remove the fragment from the view before putting in another one. Here is an implementation example here:

```
view.removeView(R.id.layout_of_fragment);
```

Comment: this helped me getting rid of my problem, tho i still haven't understood what caused it! :D